# How to add colour (i.e. red) on the dates where there are events?

Tags: android, events, calendar, android-calendar

I'm using tyczj's [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView/). I would like to add colour such as red onto dates where there are events. Have asked the same question [here](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView/issues/72) too.

Here are my codes:

Calendar.xml

```
<com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView>
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="416dp"
</com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView>
```

Calendar.java

```
ExtendedCalendarView calendar = (ExtendedCalendarView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
calendar.setOnDayClickListener(new OnDayClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDayClicked(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id, Day day) {
        day.getDay();
        int perfectmonth = day.getMonth()+1;
        perfectdate = day.getYear() + "-" + perfectmonth + "-" + day.getDay();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ perfectdate , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        accessWebService();
    }
});

Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
value = extras.getString("ad");
```

For your info, Calendar.java has imported the ExtendedCalendarView. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you could look into the adapter of this widget on github.. event colors are set based on what has been defined already..

Comment: Are you not getting any color when you set them, going by the documentation in github, you do have options to set them. What is the issue you are facing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558823/calendar-from-tyczj ?

Comment: May I know how to set the colour? In addition, this java file has imported the ExtendedCalendarView which I didn't touch anything on its files. The issue I'm facing is that I want to set up the colour to indicate on the date cell where there are events on that particular date.